# Algorithm to solve a system of linear inequalities over the natural numbers

Tags: inequality, algorithms, integer-programming, integer-lattices, mathematica

I am looking for an algorithm to solve a system of linear inequalities of the form

$$A\,\vec n + \vec c \;\geq\; 0$$

for $\vec n$ where $A$ is a matrix of integers, $\vec c$ consists of integers and $\vec n$ of natural numbers (i.e. an algorithm to find a parametric representation of all integer points inside an in general unbounded convex polytope).

The solution should look like the output of Mathematica's `Reduce` command, e.g.

```
In[1]:= Reduce[1 - n2 + n3 >= 0 && -1 + n2 >= 0 && -n1 + n2 + n3 >= 0 && n1 - n2 >= 0 && n1 - n3 >= 0 && 1 - n1 + n2 >= 0 && 3 + n2 - n3 >= 0 && n1 >= 0 && n2 >= 0 && n3 >= 0,Integers]
Out[1]= C[1] ∈ Integers && C[1] >= 0 && ((n1 == 3 + C[1] && n2 == 2 + C[1] && n3 == 1 + C[1]) || (n1 == 2 + C[1] && n2 == 1 + C[1] && n3 == 2 + C[1]) || (n1 == 2 + C[1] && n2 == 1 + C[1] && n3 == 1 + C[1]) || (n1 == 1 + C[1] && n2 == 1 + C[1] && n3 == 1 + C[1]) || (n1 == 1 + C[1] && n2 == 1 + C[1] && n3 == C[1]))
```

(here the result is a union of lines)

or

```
In[1]:= Reduce[n1 >= 0 && n2 >= 0 && n1 - n2 + 1 >= 0, Integers]
Out[1]= (C[1] | C[2]) ∈ Integers && C[1] >= 0 && C[2] >= 0 && ((n1 == C[1] + C[2] && n2 == 1 + C[2]) || (n1 == C[1] + C[2] && n2 == C[2]))
```

(a union of two planes)

Note that the solutions describe infinite numbers of integer points.

Unfortunately, the Mathematica documentation doesn't mention which algorithm is used.

I am porting an existing Mathematica package (used in particle physics) for performance reasons to C++. The only missing ingredient is an equivalent to the `Reduce` command. The algorithm is needed to rewrite multi-fold sums of the form
$$
  \sum_{n_1=0}^\infty
  \cdots
  \sum_{n_N=0}^\infty
  f(\vec n)\,
  \theta(\vec a_1\cdot\vec n + \vec c_1)
  \cdots
  \theta(\vec a_J\cdot\vec n +\vec c_J)
  \,,\quad
  \theta(x)=\begin{cases}
1\;;\; x\geq 0 \\
0\;;\; x<0
  \end{cases}
$$
to sums without $\theta$-functions.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I've added a second example where the solution is not a union of lines.

Comment: Well, to be precise, it's not lines and planes, but subsets of the integer lattice.

Comment: Take a look at [Fourier-Motzkin elimination extension to integer programming problems](https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(76)90055-8). Are you acquainted with [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic)?

Comment: You should definitely take a look at Mathematica's documentation and find out what exactly `Reduce` is spitting out.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, this problem is a subset of [Integer Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming), which is NP-Complete, so you won't find anything necessarily "efficient".

Fortunately, now that you know the name, are plenty of libraries that have fancy heuristics for finding solutions. I know about [`lp_solve`](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/), but you can choose one that's more appropriate for your project.

Comment: If I understand this correctly Integer Programming is some kind of optimization problem. I don't see how this can be used here since there is no function to maximize. The system of inequalities has infinite solutions and I am looking for a way to find all of them. The Mathematica result is a set of lines parameterized by an integer C[1].